# Clarification on topic metadata sync in MM2.0 logs

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-mirrormaker

In MM2.0 logs, I often see the following:

```
Resetting the last seen epoch of topic-partition to 0 since the associated topicId changed from null to XXXXX (org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata:402)
```

I can see that this is part of the `metadata sync` process between mirror maker and the Kafka broker but wanted to clarify a couple of points:

1. Does this happen for all `topic partition(s)` present in the Kafka broker or only the topics present in the `mm2.properties` ? I'm curious as I see this log even for topics that are not present in the `mm2.properties` file but are there in the broker.
2. Incase it's for all the topic partition(s) present in the broker, will this be a point of concern for the mirror maker replication performance if the number of topic partitions residing in the broker were to increase drastically?